# Download youtube video duration using youtube-dl PHP and ffmpeg

Tags: php, youtube, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

Is there any more efficient way to download youtube videos at a specific start and end time using youtube-dl and ffmpeg in PHP.

I currently have this, which does work, it first downloads the whole video to an mp3 file, and then crops that file to the range I set using ffmpeg, but when I only want 30 seconds or so of a 20 minute video, waiting for the full video to download doesn't seem the best way to do it.

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use YoutubeDl\YoutubeDl;

$dl = new YoutubeDl([
    'extract-audio' => true,
    'audio-format' => 'mp3',
    'audio-quality' => 0, // best
    'output' => 'videoname.%(ext)s',
]);
$dl->setDownloadPath('C:\youtubevideos');
$video = $dl->download('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDAw7vW7H0c');

$start = 60; // Start 60 seconds in to the video
$duration = 30; // Get 30 seconds after $start
$fullVideo = "C:\youtubevideos\videoname.mp3";
$shortVideo = "C:\youtubevideos\short\shortversion.mp3"; // create 30 seconds
exec("ffmpeg -ss $start -i $fullVideo -t $duration -c copy $shortVideo");
exec("DEL $fullVideo");
```

I am using youtube dl PHP https://github.com/norkunas/youtube-dl-php

Comment: As this is a wrapper for [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme), I believe the limitation is with youtube-dl itself. See this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230481/how-to-download-portion-of-video-with-youtube-dl-command